# Having trouble check in excel file in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, excel, check-in, windows-7, office

I tried to check in the file to the site. But I got this error message

```
(The system cannot find the file specified (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)).
```

I'm able to check out the file, edit, and even save the file successfully. I never have this problem before. I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is my environment: SharePoint 2010, Office Standard 2007, Windows 7 Professional (Build 7601) operating system and Internet Explorer 8.

---

This is what I have for the IE addon:

[image]

I do not have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support install in my Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking in the file from Excel or from SharePoint?

Try an IISReset.

Do you have SharePoint plugin installed on your installation of Office? All Programs -> Office -> Change -> Office Tools/Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support.

Also, do you have the plugins necessary in IE to perform Checkout? They may be disabled. IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Programs -> Manage Addons

Comment: IISReset may help you out here as suggested by @Mike

Comment: @Mike I'm checking in from SharePoint. I do not have access to the back end.

Comment: Whenever you edit the document, does it say Read-Only at the top of Excel?

Comment: No because I edit the document in edit mode.

Comment: That's not to say it will kick you into Read-Only mode. It happens often. What about Internet Explorer security? Is your SharePoint site in the trusted or local intranet zone?

Comment: The weird thing is I'm not able to discard the check out nor check in the file. I will get the same error message if I do that. If I try to change something in the file the program will lock everyone out. Nobody in my team get the same error message.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: If you don't have SharePoint Foundation Support installed, install it.

Comment: I install it in Window 7 right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4483/discussion-between-mike-and-yyc2001)